# My onload listener doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, firebug, event-listener

I know I am missing something here, but my page isn't working right...

I have a simple `init()` function tied to `window.onload`. `init()` is firing but I get a weird error such as that it cannot read the DOM element itself. I can just pop into Firebug and run `init();` from the console and that **does** work properly. It appears I am not using the proper `onload` listener. Is there a better one? Also, perhaps this is due to my use of `document.getElementsByClassName()`.

Here is the error (and then me putting `init()` into the console):
[image: Firebug displaying the error message plus the manual call to <code>init()</code>]

Here is my **relevant** code:

```
... // There is more code, I just didnt include it.

  window.addEventListener("onload", init(), false);

  function init(){
    populateText();
    populateLinks();
    populateIcons();
  }

  function populateText(){
    var texts = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
    for (i = 0; i < data.links.length; i++) {
      texts[i].innerHTML = data.links[i].text;
    }
  }

  function populateLinks(){
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
    for (i = 0; i < data.links.length; i++) {
      links[i].href = data.links[i].link;
    }
  }

  function populateIcons(){
    var icons = document.getElementsByClassName("icon");
    for (i = data.links.length; i > 0; i--) {
      icons[(data.links.length-i)].src = "screens/screen ("+i+").png";
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='iconLinks'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="link" href="" target="_blank">
          <div class="text"></div>
          <img class="icon" src=""/>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
      <a class="link" href="" target="_blank">
        <div class="text"></div>
        <img class="icon" src=""/>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="link" href="" target="_blank">
        <div class="text"></div>
        <img class="icon" src=""/>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="link" href="" target="_blank">
        <div class="text"></div>
        <img class="icon" src=""/>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="link" href="" target="_blank">
        <div class="text"></div>
        <img class="icon" src=""/>
      </a>
    </li>

... // There is more code, I just didnt include it.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass function reference to `addEventListener()`. Also the event name is [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load), not `onload`. So the call should look like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

(You could also omit the `false` as third parameter, as that is the default value.)

In your case `init()` is called first and it's return value (which is `undefined`) is then passed to the handler for the `onload` event.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna load your function until your entire DOM load finished :

JS：

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  populateText();
  populateLinks();
  populateIcons();
}
</script>
```

JQuery：

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
  populateText();
  populateLinks();
  populateIcons();
})
```